# Acces VBA DLOOKUP

Tags: ms-access, vba

```
Teller = Nz(DLookup("[Teller]", "[Lookuptable]", ("Artikel = '" & ValueArtikel & "' " And " Lookuptable= 'G'")), 0)
Noemer = Nz(DLookup("[Noemer]", "[lookuptable]", ("Artikel = ' " & ValueArtikel & " ' " And Lookuptable= " 'G' ")), 0)
```

I want to perform a DLOOKUP in acces vba but i can't find the right statement. I looked at many sites and this are the two dlookups that i think are correct but both give the error types don't match. Teller and noemer are integers, Artikel and artikelvalue and Lookuptable are strings. Sorry if this is already asked but i can't find it. i find many posts about it but i can't fixed it. And especcialy sorry for my bad english

Comment: Create your criteria as a string variable and see what you are creating, the string has `Artikel = '" & ValueArtikel & "' "` AND etc which isn't correct

Comment: Be aware if `ValueArtikel` contains quote(s) (`'`) your query fails. Escape by doubleing (`''`) , use DoubleQuotes, use a parameter query or `BuildCriteria` to avoid this.. : `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first one is close. Use variables and `Debug.Print` to help building the strings.

Ctrl+g shows the output.

```vb
strCrit = "Artikel = '" & ValueArtikel & "' And Lookuptable= 'G'"
Debug.Print strCrit
Teller = Nz(DLookup("[Teller]", "[Lookuptable]", strCrit), 0)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i found my mistake cause of you. You are my hero

Answer (score 1):

I use my own function for Lookups because Lookups have a really bad performance.

```vb
' Lookups Replacements
'---------------------

Function DLook(Expression As String, Domain As String, Optional Criteria) As Variant

  On Error GoTo Err_Handler

  Dim strSQL As String

  'DCount: strSQL = "SELECT COUNT(" & Expression & ") FROM " & Domain

  'Other replacements
  'DLookup: 
   strSQL = "SELECT " & Expression & " FROM " & Domain
  'DMax: strSQL = "SELECT MAX(" & Expression & ") FROM " & Domain
  'DMin: strSQL = "SELECT SUM(" & Expression & ") FROM " & Domain
  'DFirst: strSQL = "SELECT FIRST(" & Expression & ") FROM " & Domain
  'DLast: strSQL = "SELECT LAST(" & Expression & ") FROM " & Domain
  'DSum: strSQL = "SELECT SUM(" & Expression & ") FROM " & Domain
  'DAvg: strSQL = "SELECT AVG(" & Expression & ") FROM " & Domain

  If Not IsMissing(Criteria) Then strSQL = strSQL & " WHERE " & Criteria
  DLook = DBEngine(0)(0).OpenRecordset(strSQL, dbOpenForwardOnly)(0)

Exit Function

Err_Handler:
  MsgBox "Error. Lookup couldnt be performed" & vbNewLine & Err.Description, vbCritical

End Function
```

Called with:

```vb
If DLook("Column2", "Table1", "Column1 = " & ID) = 0 Then
  'Do stuff
End If

If DLook("Column2", "Table1") = 0 Then
  'Do other stuff
End If
```

Comment: What about making it universal with a 4. parameter (optional) for aggregate type (as enum) and a `Select Case` for the sql string? You are aware that `DBEngine(0)(0)` can point to <> `CurrentDb` (e,g if a wizard is active). I prefer a property that returns `CurrentDb` (known as `CurrentDbC`).